# Smell from Polyurethaned Floors

Tags: polyurethane

I am moving into an apt in 10 days. The landlord redid the floors and used oil based polyurethane. I am concerned about the smell as he just did this several days ago and wanted to know if it’s safe to move in within this short period of time. So it will be less than two weeks since they laid the application and move. I do have sensitivity and was concerned about the offgassing.  Please advise as to the risks. Thank you!

Comment: For most people would just recommend opening the windows, but with a sensitivity, I am not sure that would be enough, or even if you should stay there.  Would depend on your sensitivity, is it closer to it just stinks or more of a possible allergic reaction.

Comment: It only takes about24 houses for polyurethane to dry in most cases. At 2 weeks after the application there should be no real off-gassing.most people don’t realize how many things in there home are made of polyurethane foam. Things like the sponges with the scotch bright backing is one example I remember a person telling me they were deathly allergic to poly out gassing as she open a brand new sealed bad of sponges after mentioning that the sponges would out gas more than the piece she admitted she did not like the smell.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the replies. I’ve lived in another place, that was brand new snd cabinets had this horrible chemical smell. Had headaches and had to get an air purifier. But this was a very small apt. This new move is into a bigger space with lots of windows. Just concerned just due to my previous experiences! Trying to take precautions. I appreciate any advise and thanks again!